# Where are the Doctor and Martha running off to at the end of Blink?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of the Doctor Who episode Blink, Sally Sparrow catches the Doctor and Martha running off towards an adventure.  Are they running off to an adventure that occurs off screen or do we see this adventure in a later episode?

Comment: The adventure has never been televised. It's possible that some of the novels or comic stories covered it, but if it exists I'm not aware of it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The adventure is off-screen, as we must assume that *many* are. Furthermore, and this is confirmed by the DVD commentary, the writers took the opportunity of making it sound like a peculiarly bizarre adventure, since they knew they weren't going to have to figure out how to show it to us.

> SALLY: Doctor! Doctor! Doctor!
>   DOCTOR: Hello. Sorry, bit of a rush. There's a sort of thing happening. Fairly important we stop it.
>   SALLY: My God, it's you. It really is you. Oh, you don't remember me, do you?
>   **(Martha is carrying a quiver of arrows, and the Doctor has a long bow.)**
>   **MARTHA: Doctor, we haven't got time for this. The migration's started.**
>   DOCTOR: Look, sorry, I've got a bit of a complex life. Things don't always happen to me in quite the right order. Gets a bit confusing at times, especially at weddings. I'm rubbish at weddings, especially my own.
>   SALLY: Oh, my God, of course. You're a time traveller. It hasn't happened to you yet. None of it. It's still in your future.
>   DOCTOR: What hasn't happened?
>   **MARTHA: Doctor, please. Twenty minutes to red hatching.**
>   SALLY: It was me. Oh, for God's sake, it was me all along. You got it all from me.
>   DOCTOR: Got what?
>   SALLY: Okay, listen. One day you're going to get stuck in 1969. Make sure you've got this with you. You're going to need it.
>   (Sally hands her file of documents to the Doctor.)
>   MARTHA: Doctor!
>   **DOCTOR: Yeah, listen, listen, got to dash. Things happening. Well, four things. Well, four things and a lizard.**
>   SALLY: Okay. No worries. On you go. See you around some day.
>   DOCTOR: What was your name?
>   SALLY: Sally Sparrow.
>   DOCTOR: Good to meet you, Sally Sparrow.

Comment: According to [this page](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=519508), the writer actually *said* in the DVD commentary that **he made what the Doctor and Martha were doing as outrageously absurd as he could get away with, and deliberately didn't invent the full story**. Might be worth adding this to your answer?

Comment: @randal'thor: I don't have anything to quote but I've now cited the DVD commentary. Thanks

Comment: They did a similar thing in Love & Monsters - as The Doctor and Rose chase The Hoix in that Scooby-Doo-esque opening, the details of that adventure are left wide open. That became a recurring gag - seeing the tail end of a previous adventure that remains a mystery.

Comment: Jim the fish comes to mind

Answer (score 2):

The 'Red Hatching' from Blink is finally depicted in [Episode 10](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Salvation_(audio_story)) of the audio series *[Doctor Who:  Redacted](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Redacted_(audio_series))* by BBC Studios.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. The 'Your Answer' field should only be used to answer the question though, not to post tangentially-related comments. When you've earned enough [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to unlock the [comment everywhere](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege, you can leave comments beneath other users' questions or answers. In the meantime, you should focus on earning reputation by posting good questions or answers of your own. Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more.

Comment: You need to actually describe the event, not just point at a place that OP might be able to find out for themselves.

Comment: @LogicDictates, this *is* a direct answer to OPs question, just poorly fleshed out, as Valorum points out.

Comment: @WolfieSmith - Is 'the red hatchling' a place? If not, then this doesn't answer the question of _where_ the Doctor and Martha were running off to at the end of "Blink." It also doesn't clearly answer the question of whether this adventure was ever shown on-screen or not.

Comment: @LogicDictates, 'red hatching' is the *event* Martha specifically mentions in Blink that they were running off to when they meet Sally Sparrow at the end. This answer is the only current one which gives more details on what they were actually doing as per canon BBC content. Like I said, it's very incomplete, but it's far from 'tangentially related'.

Comment: @WolfieSmith - Okay, but even combining what you've said with this answer, it's still not clear to me whether the 'adventure' asked about in the question occurred on-screen or not (unless I take into account additional information, like that provided within the previous answers). This answer _would_ serve as a useful comment beneath one of the two previous answers, but it doesn't work as a standalone answer in my view, and from the way it's phrased, I'm not sure it was actually intended to.

Comment: @LogicDictates, I just think sometimes this site is too quick to criticise and discourage new contributors. We should be encouraging them to *improve* answers, not *remove* them.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the "lizard" part, I'm guessing there's a Silurian involved. We have no record of Martha ever meeting the Silurians, though. There are >>memes<< in the Internet linking it to "The Name of the Doctor" with Clara(1), River(2), Strax(3), Jenny(4), and Madame Vastra(lizard) => four things and a lizard. However, this...
1) doesn't account for the part of the red hatching
2) involves the 11th Doctor and
3) is long past the time of Martha's involvement with the Doctor.
We know this: There's likely five people involved besides the Doctor and Martha, one of which might be a Silurian. If "red hatching" is a code for something or at least not meant as an actual hatching of something red, it might be a sort of medieval festival, judging by the bow and arrows. One way or another, it's probably peaceful and doesn't involve danger the sort of which we frequently see the Doctor involved in.
But that's just my take on the whole idea.